# Is it possible to import HR schema in a postgresql database? I can't seem to find a way to do it

Tags: postgresql, schema

I tried to restore using pgadmin 4 and selected directory but i'm getting this kind of error

[image]

Comment: Does the indicated directory on T: exist?  If so, what does it contain?

Comment: It contains bunch of schema and sql files

Comment: Yes but does it contain ```toc.dat```?  Also was it created with ```pg_dump -Fd```?

Comment: No there was no. Toc.dat . I selected imported from directories option of pgadmin 4. But it could not load SQL files.I want to load those sql files into my database